# Are questions like 'Where should I report this bug' allowed?

Tags: support, asking-questions

May we ask questions on AskUbuntu if we encounter a bug, and we do not know how/where to report it? For example, one can see black screen and is unsure whether he/she should report it against xorg, unity, or whatever else. Is it allowed to ask questions on how to troubleshoot an issue **in order** to report it as a bug?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Generally yes, but it would be better to as a canonical question such as "How to find out what package to report a bug against". There is a chance your question will be closed as *too localised* if it's unlikely to be useful for the *general audience* of Ask Ubuntu.

So, if your specific question  is likely to help someone else, ask it! Otherwise it might be better to ask in one of Ubuntu's IRC channels, mailing lists, or the Ask Ubuntu chat.